# Owner of /usr/lib is not root

Tags: virtualbox, permissions, root, chown, ownership

Virtualbox program error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine .... Failed to load
>   VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_OWNER_NOT_ROOT).

Terminal output:

```
balazs@inspiron:/usr$ ls -l
total 164
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   69632 Oct 12 12:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 Apr 24 19:04 games
drwxr-xr-x  81 root   root   12288 Sep 29 11:57 include
drwxr-xr-x 200 balazs balazs 36864 Oct 12 12:27 lib
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root    4096 May 23 10:43 lib32
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   root    4096 Oct  3 14:02 local
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   12288 Oct 10 19:17 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 337 root   root   12288 Oct 12 12:27 share
drwxr-xr-x  11 root   root    4096 Oct 12 12:27 src
```

I didn't changed anything. Maybe some other installed software screwed things up. But I think /usr/lib should be owned by root.
Inside the folder everything is owned by root.

```
balazs@inspiron:/usr/lib$ ls -l | less
total 196232
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:03 accountsservice
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root         4096 Jul 16 12:49 ADM_plugins
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:04 aisleriot
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:04 apg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         4096 May 28 01:50 apr-util-1
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:02 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root        12288 Apr 24 19:03 aspell
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:03 at-spi2-core
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root        34512 Jul 11 07:51 attica_kde.so
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root         4096 Apr 24 19:04 avahi
```

How should I fix this ?

I fear I'll break my OS. I did sudo chown on that folder once and I had to reinstall everyting because sudo wasn't owned by root etc. ( a year ago ) I decided not to use Virtualbox, but now I need it.
Any help?

Comment: You appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your other accounts are merged.  Once done, you'll be able to re-edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use `chown` to change the owner:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib
```

This will change the owner of `/usr/lib` directory to root.

Comment: Sure? 


sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib

Won't it cause "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

And other problems like that?
chown recursively is a good thing on that folder?
I have very sensitive data on this OS, don't want to waste time reinstalling everything :s

Comment: Thank you. I did it. And after that "sudo gedit" and no errors. seems like it's working. thx ^^

Comment: Virtualbox output: "Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000) (rc=-10)"  oh snap. Starts again .....

Comment: System program problem detected.... Sytstem program problem reporter crashed. I fear restarting my OS :s :( I'll quickly save everything to a USB storage drive then probably reintall the whole thing.

Comment: @balazs All of these doesn't have nothing to do with `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo chown root.root /usr /usr/lib
```

Do you need guarantee that `/usr` and `/usr/lib` are with root owner for user and group? Usually you can found user 501.501 in this directories.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this command:

```
sudo chmod 4711 /usr/lib/virtualbox/Virtualbox
```

[Here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=11154) is the link that solved my problem witch is similar to yours.

Hope this will solve your problem.